# JQuery: is it possible to set <a> tag style to change on click?

Tags: jquery, click, styles

OK - I know this one might be a long shot but I was wondering:

I have some a tags that link off to other pages and basically I want the styling around them to change when the user clicks them (so if the user holds the mouse button down for 3 seconds they can see the style change).

So far I have:

```
$(function() {

//MOUSE CLICK EVENTS
$('#mainmenu a').click(function() {
            $('#mainmenu li').addClass("menupressed");
});

});//END ONLOAD
```

But it doesnt work. Is this possible? Am I on the right track?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

EDIT: Mark up as request:

```
          <div class="content">
              <ul class="mainmenu">
                  <a href="page1.html"><li>Page1</li></a>
                  <a href="page2.html"><li>Page2</li></a>
                  <a href="page3.html"><li>Page3</li></a>
              </ul>    
          </div><!--content-->
```

Comment: If you want to change the style on the `<a>` element why are you using a `li` selector?

Also, you may want to try with the `mousedown` event instead of `click`.

Comment: In theory this is totally possible.  Like Juan mentioned, are you adding a class to the mainmenu listitems on purpose?

Comment: Please provide some clear html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the markup in your question, you need to reference the container's class and not with its id as it doesn't have one.

If you want to do it on click:

```
$('.mainmenu a').click(function() {
            $('li', this).addClass("menupressed");
});
```

If on mousedown:

```
$('.mainmenu a').mousedown(function() {
    $('li', this).addClass("menupressed");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the markup is invalid, you should not wrap a block element by an inline one.

```
     <div class="content">
          <ul class="mainmenu">
              <li><a href="page1.html">Page1</a></li>
              <li><a href="page2.html">Page2</a></li>
              <li><a href="page3.html">Page3</a></li>
          </ul>    
      </div><!--content-->
```

also you are selecting a class by using id selector, try this:

```
$(function() {

//MOUSE CLICK EVENTS
$('.mainmenu a').click(function() {
     $(this).addClass("menupressed");
})

});//END ONLOAD
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KLjH3/1/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a markup

```
<ul><li><a></li>...</ul>

$(function() {
  $('#mainmenu a').on('click', function() {
     $(this).parent().addClass("menupressed");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `click` event is triggered when the mouse button is pressed and then released. If you want to be able to see the change when the user "holds the mouse button down for 3 seconds" as you said, you should use the `mousedown` event.

You can compare both behaviors on their respective jquery pages:

http://api.jquery.com/click/

http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/

Keep in mind however that if the user holds down the mouse button, then moves the mouse outside the anchor element and *then* releases it, the link will not be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

To add a click to your specific `<a>` element, just lose the internal selector:

```
$('#mainmenu a').click(function() {
  this.addClass('menupressed');
});
```

If you need to add the class to the next `<li>` parent element:

```
$('#mainmenu a').click(function() {
  this.closest('li').addClass('menupressed');
});
```

This uses the `.closest()` method, found here: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0):

This is will add class if held for 3 seconds.

**Edited to work with class**

```
var hammertime=0;
$('.mainmenu a').bind('mousedown',function() {
    hammertime= window.setTimeout((function(elem){
     return function(){
        elem.addClass("menupressed");
     }
   })($(this).children('li')),3000) // Edit: If li is child, then use children('li')
})
.bind('mouseup',function() {
     window.clearTimeout(hammertime);
})
```

Edit:

Also make sure to wrap the whole thing in that, to be executed on load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   /* the code here */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS to change the styling of the link when it becomes active

See an example here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_link

```
a:link {color:#FF0000;}    /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#00FF00;} /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#FF00FF;}   /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#0000FF;}  /* selected link */
```

So a:active is the one you need to do what you requested. All the styling that needs to be done can be put in there.